# How to count online people connected to my web site with jQuery or st?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i created a web site with asp.net 4.0 and now i need to count online people that connected to my web site.
how do i do this with JQuery?

Comment: The counting has to be done server side. jQuery runs client side.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try Google Analytics instead?  It's free, you don't have to write any code, and you'll get way more than a hit counter out of it--you'll get breakdowns by browser, screen resolution, geography, all sorts of stuff.

Comment: Thanks,but i just need show number of online users graphically,so i decided to use jquery.Google Analytics is great but i do not need all of them,

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to create a "heartbeat" on your page that pings the server every x seconds with an ajax call and a unique session ID.  On the server, you can log/count these pings/id's and get a rough estimate (based on the last x seconds), of how many people are on your site at any given time.  Don't forget to reset your counter after every tally.

Since you're using ASP.NET, you have a few different server side options.  Some people prefer to create a standalone .aspx page that reads parameters passed via querystring and call it via ajax.  Personally, I'd [create a web handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) (.ashx) because they are particularly useful for stuff like this.  Others would say the "right" way would be to [call page webmethods with simple ajax calls](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).  If you're using MVC, then it's even easier.  Just [set up a controller method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269.aspx) that reads some querystring parameters and send requests to it.  Ultimately its up to you to decide which way will work best for your app -- they all do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you,i think "Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods" and using page methods is easier for me to implement,so i must define a page method to count online users and call this after x seconds?how do i do this? what about count users in Session_start? which one is bettr?

Comment: So,let's say you "count users in Session_start", then what?  Nothing will ever decrement the number of of users.

Comment: this is exactly my problem,,in Session_end Method i decrease from counter identifier but this decrements show very late

Comment: @MattDawdy: Good point. Updated with tip to reset counter and also added blurb for generic web handlers.  I totally forgot about those, and they're perfect for these types of things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally make a handler (.ashx) but that's because I'm so comfortable with them.  Use the heartbeat code outlined by @ajax81, but you would return (on that same call) the # of active users.

1. Assign a unique session id to each user that comes to your page. If
   you are using aspx pages and session state, you've pretty much got
   this already.  In session_start is where you'd create a session
   variable and assign it a unique identifier (I'd use a guid created
   on the fly), storing it in Session["userguid"] and in some
   persistent storeage.  Easiest way would be a simple table in a DB.
2. Client script (jquery ajax) would send a request to foo.ashx.  It
   can even really be an empty request.  Use the jQuery setTimeOut type
   functions to call this on every page, every minute.
3. In your handler, it would get a request, figure out who it came
   from, and update the "Last Updated" date of that particular user
   (which you'd get from Session["userguid"].
4. Go through all of your "active users" table and delete ones that
   haven't been updated in 5 minutes or so.
5. Get the new count of "active users" and return that to the client
   page.  The client page could then display the number in any way it
   chooses.

This is all untested, but the theory should be sound.  I just don't have time to write your full app for you.  ;)

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

        Guid sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Session["sessionGuid"] = sessionId;
        // Write code to store this in a table -- "INSERT INTO myTable (sessionGuid, dateCreated, dateUpdated) VALUES (@sessionGuid, getdate(), getdate()) ; "

    }
```

In your pages:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo.ashx",
  context: document.body
}).done(function( data ) { 
  $(someobject).html(data);
});
```

Code for foo.ashx:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Guid sessionGuid = (Guid)context.Session["sessionGuid"];

        // Write code to update table "UPDATE myTable SET dateUpdated = getdate() where sessionId = @sessionGuid ; "

        // Write statement to delete all items older than x minutes "DELETE from myTable WHERE dateUpdated < dateadd(minute, -10, getdate()) ; "

        // Get cound of existing real users: "SELECT count(*) FROM myTable ;"

        // Return that value.

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(YourValue);
    }
```

Comment: Would you please explain this with an example with source code?

Comment: What part?  The steps I listed is probably a couple hundred lines of code.

Comment: I exaggerated.  Although, with really putting in the DB access code, error checking, doing some other checks to make sure that the session id still exists in the table, etc., maybe it would end up being a few hundred lines.